# What's a good SINGLE word to mean emit sound?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I would like to use a single word to express emitting sound specifically to be used in programming code.

If I used 2 words it would be something like PLAY SOUND but I would like to avoid delimiters such as space, and hyphens if possible.

Ideally it would be something that is understandable and used already in code.

Comment: A few things. Asking for help [naming things](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), whether in code or otherwise, is not considered to be on-topic. But, I guess we can just consider that background information. The more important thing is that you need to specify how you would like to be able to use this word, *in English*: it's a single word, but do you want a verb, a noun modifier, or what? Give an example sentence. Something like "the speakers [emit sound]." Answers will be based on that example sentence, rather than your need for a programming name.

Comment: It would be a command such as GET, SEND, POST, DISPLAY, SAVE, DELETE, COPY, CUT, PASTE...

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about giving things artificial names in computer programs.

Comment: I don't understand how this is off-topic when there is and I am using a "single-word-requests" tag and it is used very often, and the title clearly requests a single word.

Comment: Single word requests are on-topic when they are requesting a word to be used in an English-language context (like in an example sentence); this is considered to fall under "English language usage". They are not on-topic when requesting a word to be used in programming code; this is considered "naming," which is off-topic. The requirement for a sample sentence is listed in the description of the ["single-word-requests"](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) tag, although it may not be the easiest thing to find.

Comment: You haven't said what sort of sound. It could be,  'beep', 'speak',  'play' etc. It could even be 'sound'. How about giving us a clue?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It could be any kind of sound.

Comment: What's wrong with 'sound' then?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with sound, but I have never seen it used in this context so I have had some doubt towards using it, plus I have rarely heard it used as a verb so have doubted its common modern day usage. I included "good" in the title because popularity is also important.

Comment: "Programming" is far too general/vague a "context" to mean anything particular wrt sounds. Either drop that context or (preferably) specify the context better.

Comment: In Victorian English, the word "ejaculate" is used to mean "make a noise". Try that.

Comment: "popularity"?  among computers?  Or are you concerned about your own popularity, or lack thereof, for choosing a "bad" name for a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single word for this is the verb to *sound*.

This is the most general, since you do not indicate either a particular kind of sound or a particular source of sound (or anything else).

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the accepted answer so I will accept it. I thought there may be a more scientific word out there but if it hasn't been stated yet it is either too obscure or doesn't exist.
My main problem with sound was that it is commonly a noun so using by itself would be hard to distinguish as articles are often dropped for single words, but as English grammar seems to work that way I don't think I can expect something more suitable.

Comment: You said it is to be a command.  Certainly your programming language/ environment specifies command syntax. I notice tge examples you gave of commands were in ALL CAPS. This alone might identify SOUND as a command.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Where did I (or anyone) say anything about "*it*" (what?) being a "*command*"? And where do you see "ALL CAPS"? What is this all about?

Answer (score 1):

"Speak" is the word used to command dogs to emitting sound. Normally it denotes verbal communication, but you could borrow this usage for your work.

"Sound" itself is also a verb.

Comment: It can also be the subject. For example: "The horn sounded"  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4xT3CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT834&dq=%22the+horn+sounded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMIzuLmqpvcyAIVCVUaCh2Rmwpz#v=onepage&q=%22the%20horn%20sounded%22&f=false

Comment: Thank you. Speak is probably what is most used in programming as a verb, but I will avoid it because it can not be combined with other sounds naturally. Say could be used instead, but sound seems more appropriate for sounds only. I will be using sound instead.